# How to add delay between jquery steps transition (jquery steps plugin)

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout

I am using http://www.jquery-steps.com/Examples#advanced-form plugin.

How can I add delay between the two steps?

I have tried adding the timeout function in `onStepChanging` and `onStepChanged` but it's not working.

Here's what my code looks like:

```
var form = $("#example-advanced-form").show();

form.steps({
    headerTag: "h3",
    bodyTag: "fieldset",
    transitionEffect: "slideLeft",
    onStepChanging: function (event, currentIndex, newIndex)
    {
        // Allways allow previous action even if the current form is not valid!
        if (currentIndex > newIndex)
        {
            return true;
        }
        // Forbid next action on "Warning" step if the user is to young
        if (newIndex === 3 && Number($("#age-2").val()) < 18)
        {
            return false;
        }
        // Needed in some cases if the user went back (clean up)
        if (currentIndex < newIndex)
        {
            // To remove error styles
            form.find(".body:eq(" + newIndex + ") label.error").remove();
            form.find(".body:eq(" + newIndex + ") .error").removeClass("error");
        }
        form.validate().settings.ignore = ":disabled,:hidden";
        return form.valid();
    },
    onStepChanged: function (event, currentIndex, priorIndex)
    {
        // Used to skip the "Warning" step if the user is old enough.
        if (currentIndex === 2 && Number($("#age-2").val()) >= 18)
        {
            form.steps("next");
        }
        // Used to skip the "Warning" step if the user is old enough and wants to the previous step.
        if (currentIndex === 2 && priorIndex === 3)
        {
            form.steps("previous");
        }
    },
    onFinishing: function (event, currentIndex)
    {
        form.validate().settings.ignore = ":disabled";
        return form.valid();
    },
    onFinished: function (event, currentIndex)
    {
        alert("Submitted!");
    }
}).validate({
    errorPlacement: function errorPlacement(error, element) { element.before(error); },
    rules: {
        confirm: {
            equalTo: "#password-2"
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to delay?

Comment: The progress of step 1 to step 2.

Answer (score 0):

how about this

```
setTimeout(function(){ /*your function*/ }, 3000);
```

https://www.w3schools.com/JSREF/met_win_setTimeout.asp

Comment: Tried the standard timeOut in both `onStepChanging` & `onStepChanged` but no success.